# How to Custom Sort IEnumerable<> data

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable

im having an Enumerable object  "inventories" which return me below data

```
[
  {
     "EligibleQuantity":11,
     "ValidFrom":"\/Date(1620770400000)\/",
     "Url":"AAA.com",
     "Distributor":{
        "Id":null,
        "Name":"AAA",
        "Image":"A.png"
     }
  },
  {
     "EligibleQuantity":22,
     "ValidFrom":"\/Date(1620770500000)\/",
     "Url":"BBB.com",
     "Distributor":{
        "Id":null,
        "Name":"BBB",
        "Image":"B.png"
     }
  },
  {
     "EligibleQuantity":33,
     "ValidFrom":"\/Date(1620230400000)\/",
     "Url":"DDD.com",
     "Distributor":{
        "Id":null,
        "Name":"DDD",
        "Image":"D.png"
     }
  }
```

]

since im using `inventories.OrderBy(d => d.Distributor.Name); by Enumerable object is getting sorted as per name.

But how can I sort it based on specific name such that, that particular name will always come on top and then the rest of the names data.
`
for example if i provide name BB then expected result will be as per below:

```
[
   {
     "EligibleQuantity":22,
     "ValidFrom":"\/Date(1620770500000)\/",
     "Url":"BBB.com",
     "Distributor":{
        "Id":null,
        "Name":"BBB",
        "Image":"B.png"
     }
  },
  {
     "EligibleQuantity":11,
     "ValidFrom":"\/Date(1620770400000)\/",
     "Url":"AAA.com",
     "Distributor":{
        "Id":null,
        "Name":"AAA",
        "Image":"A.png"
     }
  },     
  {
     "EligibleQuantity":33,
     "ValidFrom":"\/Date(1620230400000)\/",
     "Url":"DDD.com",
     "Distributor":{
        "Id":null,
        "Name":"DDD",
        "Image":"D.png"
     }
  }
```

]

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Distributor.Name == "BB").ThenBy(x => x.Distributor.Name)` ?

Comment: this is exactly that I'm looking for thank you so much